# Cannot DeleteTheme in SharePoint Online Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, theme

I created/added a Theme in SharePoint online using following commands. And provided all the details/parameters.

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $adminSiteUrl –Credentials (Get-Credential)
Add-PnPTenantTheme -Identity $themeName -Palette $palette -IsInverted $false
```

Theme is added successfully and I can select this new theme from change the look option.

But now I want to delete this theme. But I cannot find any option to delete it.

I also tried `Remove-PnPTenantTheme` but I am getting following error.

`Remove-PnPTenantTheme : Unknown Error
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-PnPTenantTheme -Identity "BASF_Orange"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Remove-PnPTenantTheme], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.RemoveTenantTheme`

Can anyone please guide me on how to delete this theme.

THanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the **-name** parameter than **-identity** parameter.

Example:

```
Remove-PnPTenantTheme -name $theme.Name
```

Or

You can try out the below code:

Inside the foreach loop, add if condition to check your theme - it will ensure that your custom theme is readable through the PnP command then inside that same if perform the **"Remove-PnPTenantTheme -name $theme.Name"**

```
$adminUrl= "https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$sparksjoy = "Cat Lovers United", "Multicolored theme"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminUrl -UseWebLogin
$themes = Get-PnPTenantTheme | where {-not ($sparksjoy -contains $_.Name)}
$themes | Format-Table Name
if ($themes.Count -eq 0) { break }
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to start deleting (CTRL + C to exit)"
$progress = 0
$total = $themes.Count
foreach ($theme in $themes)
{
   if ($theme.Name -eq "Your theme name which you want to delete")
   {
    $progress++
    write-host $progress / $total":" $theme.Name
    Remove-PnPTenantTheme -name $theme.Name
   }
}
```

Source:

[DOES IT SPARK JOY? POWERSHELL SCRIPTS FOR KEEPING YOUR DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT TIDY AND SPOTLESS](https://laurakokkarinen.com/does-it-spark-joy-powershell-scripts-for-keeping-your-development-environment-tidy-and-spotless/)

Comment: Hi Habibur thanks for the reply. But I already tried this code also I tried both `Name` and `Identity`. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to delete the custom theme:

```
Remove-SPOTheme -Name "Custom Theme Name"
```

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spotheme?view=sharepoint-ps